# Access legacy ai-platform models

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I would like to list models which are deployed on AiPlatform with the google aiplatform python api. I can get my list of models when I run `gcloud ai-platform models list` but when I use the python API with:

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform
aiplatform.init(location='us-central1', project='project_name')
aiplatform.Model.list()
```

I get the list of the models which are deployed on VertexAI **not** google AiPlatform.
Is there a python API that can access the AiPlatform and not VertexAI.
Cheers in advance
Robin

Comment: Notice that [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/introduction-unified-platform) brings AutoML and AI Platform into an unified API. And one of the recommendations is to use different Endpoints for each product(one for Vertex, one for AI Platform). By using this Python API, you can add [filters to the `list()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.Model#google_cloud_aiplatform_Model_list) to bring you the models that you look for.